# Python error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and stackoverflow, so apologies if I don't know much. I have recently picked up Python, and got started with it. I have been attempting to make a login for admin thing, but I seem to be getting an error. I have tried using a for statement, but I seem to get the error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Here's my code...

```
username = input("Please enter your username: ")
for name in username (3):
    if username == 'admin':
        break
    else:
        print("You've given incorrect credentials thrice.")
        import sys
        sys.exit("Exiting...")
while True:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if password == 'KhS9':
        break

print("Welcome admin!")
```

Any help on this?

*EDIT*

Apologies if I was not clearer, I was attempting to try and make something in which you need to type in. The for loop was used to try and get the sentence "Please enter your username" to repeat 3 times, then to show up with the sentence "You've given incorrect credentials 3 times" if the input does not match what I have set it to be (I set it as 'admin')

Comment: What is it you expect this part to do? `for name in username (3)`

Comment: `username` is a string.  `username(3)` attempts to call it as a function with the argument 3.  That's an error.  Also, why do you have the `for` loop?  You have a single name, so you don't need to try to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's that?

```
for name in username (3):
```

`Username` is a string, not a function.

If you want three first letters, just do

username = username[3]

And the script:

```
username = input("Please enter your username: ")[5]
if username == 'admin':
    break
else:
    print("You've given incorrect credentials thrice.")
    import sys
    sys.exit("Exiting...")

while True:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if password == 'KhS9':
        break

print("Welcome admin!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
for i in range(3):
    #some code
```

That means that any code put where some code is will run three times. However your else statement will evaluate to true and will thus break the loop on the first run. This means you need modify it somehow - add a counter variable.

Consider your `while True` loop will run until the correct password is entered. Insecure?

Just something on syntax - its good profession to import something at the top of the module (page) even if it means you dont use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you implement that idea properly:
    admin_name = 'abc'   # Default user name (unencrypted=insecure).
    admin_pass = 'cde'   # Default password (unencrypted=insecure).

```
max_attempts = 3     # Maximum number of times a user can try.
attempt = 0          # Initial condition when the programme is launched.

# Hereby, we'll take invalid attempts as an error, but instead of breaking the
# programme, we will later handle (via "exceptions" the error, and issue
# additional guidance.
try:

    # This is an event loop. It will run for as long as the condition set is true.
    while attempt < max_attempts:

        uname = input('Username: ')  # User is directed to enter the username.
        password = input('pass: ')   # User is directed to enter the password.

        # Values entered by the user are validated.
        if uname == admin_name and password == admin_pass:
            # If the entries are valid, the event loop is broken, and anything
            # written afterwards ( after the exceptions) will now be executed,
            # unless directed otherwise (e.g. a certain function is called)
            # before the "break".
            print('Welcome Admin')
            break

        else:
            # If the entries are invalid, but the maximum number of attempts
            # are not reached, one is added to the attempts, followed by a
            # warning. "continue" means that the rest of the loop is no longer
            # executed, and the event loop automatically moves onto the
            # forthcoming loop immediately. This is not essential here, but I
            # put it in case something else is added to the event loop.
            attempt += 1

            if attempt == max_attempts:
                # if the maximum number of attempts are reached in this loop, a
                # warning is displayed, and the next cycle would not be run
                # automatically. It is best to terminate the programme afterwards,
                # so the following code wouldn't run.
                raise RuntimeError("\nYou've reached the maximum number of attempts allowed.")

            else:
                print('Wrong credentials.\n Try again or press <ctrl+c> to exit.\n')
                continue


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # "KeyboardInterrupt" is a special exception raised only when the
    # programme is broken out of using <ctrl+c>. In that case, this piece of
    # code is  run.
    print('Terminated by the user.\nGood-bye.')

except RuntimeError as e:
    # This is handling of the errors raised above. The value of "e" is equal
    # the value given to the relevant function (RuntimeError in this case)
    # when it was raised.
    print(e)
```

Needless to mention that this is an insecure way of storing your admin password. Perhaps take advantage of the Python's `crypt` module to encrypt the password?

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier, I am quite new to python, and I am still learning. What exactly are modules in python, and how can I use this 'crypt' module?

Comment: Modules are classes (or sometimes functions, as you may not know which it is unless you see the code) that exist in libraries.  You can read more about encryption in Python in here: [ https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/crypto.html ] . Also, if this, or any other answer addresses your question, please mark it as such so the thread is closed and the question is marked as answered in the board. Or go ahead and ask more! :)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could use the 'crypt' module on my piece of code?

Comment: Also, I would appreciate it a lot if you could explain each step in the code you have given above, as I just do not understand it...

Comment: Try is a method to handle exceptions, and issue warnings or errors as required. Read more here [ https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html ]. Examples of cryptography is Python can be found here: [ http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-and-cryptography-with-pycrypto/ ]. Although I suggest you read more on cryptography in Wikipedia too. I cannot provide you with examples here, because it would be irrelevant to the question raised here, and also against StackOverflow policy. But I'd be happy to help you if you get in touch some other way. You can learn much by reading the links though.

Comment: I tried to test your code, but when i get the username and password wrong 3 times, it still says 'Wrong credentials. Try again or press <ctrl+c> to exit. Welcome Admin'.

Comment: Something must have broken when I was transferring the code to the browser. I'll check.

Comment: Here, I reorganised the code slightly. It must behave as expected now. Sorry, I hadn't tested it.